# unable to show Time to Response(TTR) values on GCP Dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, cloud, google-cloud-shell

I need your help , actually i need to create a dasboard in GCP to show TTR Time , TTR response via fetching logs from GCP logging that i am writting using script but unable to achieve it.

Below is command i am using:

gcloud logging write  logging/user/TTR4 '{"Gremblin_correlation_exec_id": "correlation_id","SenerioName": "Senerio1","ServiceName": "Service1","SubsystemName": "subsystem1","TTRTime": 500,"EndTimestamp": "2020-11-30 06:06:56+00:00","Node_ipfirst": "10.128.0.55:80","node_ipsecound": "10.128.0.6:80","starttimestamp": "2020-11-30 05:58:08+00:00" }' --payload-type=json

i am getting jason data but not able to show it on dasboard like TTRTime above 500 using filter based upon service name and subsystemName.

Comment: Even if you change your request filter, you don't get te TTR time with an higher value than 500?

Comment: What filter are you using in Cloud Monitoring?

Comment: I need 500 in scorecard without timeseries, when I log a new ttr like 600 it should update that based on selected filter like subsystem correlation id and all

Comment: I think you're going to achieve these by using log based metrics: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics  
  
if you are already using this feature please share the filter that you are using.